# Why Sum and Product aren't Functors

Tags: haskell, typeclass

[`Sum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Sum) defined in base 4.7.0.2 doesn't have `Functor` instance. Why?

For example types defined in `semigroups` package have `Functor`, `Applicative` and `Monad` on e.g. `Min`, which behave likeIdentity` - makes sense to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the main reason these are not `Functor` instances is that you have not yet submitted a code review to make them so. You can file a ticket on [Trac](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc), then submit a code review on [Phabricator](https://phabricator.haskell.org/). The preferred Phabricator workflow (using Arcanist), along with other details, can be found [here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Phabricator).

While you're doing that, you should probably also make them instances of `Applicative`, and `Monad`. You should also add `Foldable` and `Traversable` instances for them in `Data.Foldable` and `Data.Traversable`, respectively.

If you want me to guess why nobody else did this:

While `Sum` and `Product` can hold things of any type, the `Monoid` instances only make sense for `Num` instances. The type of `fmap` thus feels a bit oddly general. This, however, is not really a good reason not to make them `Functor` instances.

Comment: My use case for `Functor` is to do e.g. `fromIntegral <$> s`. And I guess changing something in `base` isn't just about submitting a patch: https://wiki.haskell.org/Library_submissions

Comment: @phadej, what I meant to say is that you're right; you need to email the libraries list. But it's almost certain to be approved. There's a general view that if there's exactly one sensible way to make a type an instance of a class, then that should be done at the definition point to avoid orphans.

Comment: I bet this is intentional. It kind of goes against the spirit of `Functor` if it only makes sense to end up with a `Num` instance inside and there is no way to express that restriction with the `Functor` type class that `base` comes with.

Comment: @DavidYoung, it only needs to be that way once you want to use the `Monoid` instance. Before that, anything really is allowed, and makes sense in context. You might even want something like `f <$> s1 <*> s2` to combine two numbers that have already been packaged up, in which case you'll briefly have a `Sum (m -> n)`. How often you might want such a thing I don't really know. But the only time I've seen "no one will want that" get in the way of sensible class instances is `KProxy`, and we'll see how long that lasts.